# ActiveRecord model defaults for excluding certain query conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, default

Is it possible in AR to exclude certain conditions by default so you don't have to define them in all your application queries?

- for example exclude for model Profile all where Profile.activate == false?

I have lots of AR queries and now have in each of them a statement .where(:active => true ) to prevent the false one's to be added to the recordset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out default_scope, it seems to do what you want: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope